# How is winter time in Busan, South Korea?

Tags: international-travel, tips-and-tricks, weather-and-climate, south-korea, winter

I will travel around early January. I want to know from someone who has been there around this time if it's extremely cold?

Comment: I've experience freezing rain (or tiny hail or something) in Seoul, which was mighty uncomfortable. I'm not sure if Busan is far enough further south to make much difference but it feels more exposed to the sea, which could make it worse in some ways. Interested to see the answers.

Comment: Define extremely cold. Weather averages are easy enough to find on Wiki.